# Dynamically update field when using quick edit in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I’ve used a rule in infopath to update a Boolean field based on whether or not content is in another field. It works when I submit the form, but not when I quick edit the list . 
If I configure the field as a calculated field in sharepoint it works, but then infopath does not have the option for a calculated field and when I publish the form it overwrites the calculated field. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the rule?

According to my test, I create a Form Load rule for the list form and the rule work successfully both in new form and edit form:

1. I add a text box field and a Check Box field in the form.
   [image]
2. Add a Form Load rule though Data Tab->Rules->Form Load.
   [image]
3. Then rule sets as below:

[image]

4. In the list, I edit a item that field1 is blank and field2 is No, then the field2 updates to Yes when the edit form opening.

[image]
[image]
Did you create the rule same as me? If I misunderstand your issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I'm sure I did something to mess it up. though, I switched to SharePoint designer and have it working perfectly now.